# IPhone remember where you've been

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there any way an iPhone app can remember the path it took to get to a particular page. For instance Home -> Subcategories page with parameter Category = Electronics -> List of products with parameter Category = MP4 players -> Product page with parameters productId = 398483 and productName = iPod Touch 8GB

so that if I go back from product Page I will get to the List of products page with the right parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use a [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you could track the view information as you move through the views that get pushed and popped.